# elasticsearch_dsl: Filter by nested field

Tags: python, elasticsearch-dsl

I have the data in following format:

```
{_source:"@fields": {
          "code": 200,
          "relativeCreated": 5969784.005880356,
          "process": 16,
          "module": "run",
          "funcName": "main",
          "threadName": "MainThread",
          "filename": "run.py",
          "levelno": 20,
          "processName": "MainProcess",
          "lineno": 210,
          "node": "4",
          "thread": 19255376,
          "package": 977,

      }
}
```

And what I want to do is to make a filter to get only items where package is 977. Was trying to do the following `search.filter("term", **{'@fields.package': 937})`
But it does not seem to filter anything.

Answer (score 1):

If the field **package** inside **@fields** is nested then you might have to use nested filters, check your mapping and confirm about the field type, for nested filters you can implement it in this way:

```
search.filter("nested", path = '@fields' filter=F('term', '@fields.package': 937))
```

Comment: from where that F is coming ? 
Importing from elasticsearch-dsl?

Comment: @SaadMirza It seems [from the changelog](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Changelog.html#section-22) that using `F` for filters has been removed in favor of `Q` as filters are a shorthand for queries anyway. It seems that the above could be re-written as: `search.filter("nested", path='@fields' query=Q('term', '@fields.package': 937))`